Does double negation make sentences ambiguous?
I'm having a discussion about if this sentence is logically right or wrong or ambiguous.
What do you think?

If you do not at least have one or two beliefs that your culture would not retaliate against you for voicing, you ultimately do not have any beliefs, only echoes.


Could you please cite the source of your example ((title, author, etc).

The idea of a retaliating culture is so vast and finally so lacking in definition in the present context that I believe it contributes to making more opaque the whole reasoning expressesd by this sentence.

"To voice" is constructed with an object (voice their opinion, voice your grievances, etc.)

@BillJ source is private.

@LPH I agree with you, its opaque. But I think there is still something to say about the logical structure of the sentence.

@Fee, well, you shouldn't use it then, since it is a rule of this site that examples are supported by title and author.

It's wrong ... you need to get rid of the second not and change "not retaliate" to "retaliate".  This is not a sentence, like "I can't get no satisfaction", where a double negation can mean the same as a single negation. Those sentences come from various dialects, but are limited to specific grammatical forms.

This seems to be a request for proofreading without the provision of further information. We certainly can't judge if it's logically right or wrong without knowing the intended meaning and context - and questions about logic probably belong on Philosophy SE. If you have a specific problem, set out what you think it means, where precisely you think the problem lies, and any other research you've done.

would not retaliate ≠ would retaliate
This is not double negation. Double negation is a doubled negator in the same clause, like saying not not in I haven’t NOT said anything. It is not ambiguous because the second negator cancels out the first, yielding a logical result that you have said something after all.
But that’s not what your sentence is doing. Your subordinate clause instead has a spurious negation inserted before retaliate, one which makes no sound sense for the meaning you’re attempting to convey here:

If you do not at least have one or two beliefs that your culture would not retaliate against you for voicing, you ultimately do not have any beliefs, only echoes.

This class of mistake can sometimes be seen when translating too literally from a source language that has different rules about negation and negative concord than English has. For example, French infamously has a ne explétif under certain sorts of clauses. So a sentence like:

Unless your culture would retaliate against you for expressing at least one or two of your beliefs, you ultimately have no beliefs at all, only echoes.

might show up in French with an extra ne inserted before the retaliation verb, something along the lines of:

À moins que ta culture ne riposte contre toi pour avoir exprimé au moins une ou deux de tes croyances, tu n’as finalement aucune croyance, juste des échos.

When you translate such clauses into English, you must ignore that ‘extra’ would-be negator to produce a simpler construction. That’s because it is not here a negator in French, just something mechanical one sometimes does.

Bravo for the clarity.
